# Detecting air printers

Tags: xcode

I want to detect air printers in my app and connect to them. How can I do this for iOS3.1, 3.2, 3.3, ... ??? For iOS4.2 is supported the UIPrintInteractionController but this don't work on lower versions.

Comment: At this point you would be looking at a mountain of work to support pre 4.2 versions.  You have to ask your self if the added work is worth supporting the very few users who have not upgraded for the last 2 years.  And furthermore, those users are the least likely to be spending money on apps or even downloading them in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It's an iOS 4.2 feature; the relevant code is in iOS 4.2 only. You'd have to reverse engineer and reimplement the entire protocol.